Can the non-distributing end user of a software violate the MIT or GPL license?
Company A wants to buy software from company B for in-house use - that is, it will only be installed on machines of company A.
Said commercial software package contains code and utilities licensed under MIT and GPL in addition to the closed source parts. (This part is clearly declared by company B.)
Does company A need to worry whether company B fully complies with all its open source licenses?
For example, if a copyright holder detects violation of a license and forces company B to shut down, could said copyright holder -- for MIT or GPL code -- go after company A for having used or continuing to use the product? Have there been similar examples like with patent trolling?

For GPL, definitely not.  Firstly, GPLv3 s2 "explicitly affirms your unlimited permission to run the unmodified Program", with no further obligations.  Secondly, s10 grants you "a license from the original licensors, to run, modify and propagate that work, subject to this License".  Thirdly, s9 notes that "You are not required to accept this License in order to receive or run a copy of the Program".
So company A doesn't need anyone's permission to run the GPL program, and nobody can come after company A for doing so.
If A decides to start distributing copies of this software, and note that can include transfer to external entities working for the company (see eg this FAQ entry), then A will have source-distribution obligations.  If A can't meet those because B has not provided the source, then in consequence they cannot distribute the GPL software outside the company (s12 makes this explicit).
GPLv2 works in the same way, broadly speaking.
For MIT software, again, provided no onward distribution occurs, I don't see that A has any obligations to fulfil, so cannot be sued for failure to fulfil them.
If B was simply lying about the software being under GPL/MIT, and they have instead distributed software that was under some proprietary licence and to which they had no rights, then A will need to stop using it, or risk a lawsuit from the original rightsholder.  But that risk is not peculiar to software that's advertised as freely-licensed; it's equally  true for completely-proprietary software where, say, a licence is purchased from an unauthorized agent.

A high profile case of the scenario in your last paragraph happened about 15 years ago.  MS hired an outside firm to provide a user friendly tool to convert a DVD ISO image of their new OS into a bootable USB stick.  Instead of writing a tool from scratch (or only using 3rd party code that could be incorporated into a closed source application) as they were hired to do, the outside firm just reskinned existing GPL tools, and inevitably got caught. https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/11/windows-7-tool-violates-gpl-microsoft-will-open-source-it/
